# functionning html not working on wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, inline

I'm trying to add the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html version="HTML+RDFa 1.0">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<link href="https://socialhub.s3.amazonaws.com/production/styles/sr-socialhub.carousel.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Note - you may not need to include jQuery if you already have it. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://socialhub.s3.amazonaws.com/production/scripts/app-carousel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="ngSocialHub" ui-view
  ng-social-hub-carousel
  ng-social-hub-customer="news"
  ng-social-hub-board-id="out-and-about"
  ng-social-hub-infinite-scroll="true"
  ng-social-hub-dialog-enabled="false"
  ng-social-hub-locale="en"
  ng-social-hub-facebook-appid="<YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID HERE>"
  ng-social-hub-interval="5000"
  ng-social-hub-disable-user-actions="false"
  ng-social-hub-disable-carousel-indicator="true"
></div>
</body>
</html>
```

into a page as inline code to my site http://dtcm.co.nz, for some reason this code doesn't seem to work with my wordpress based site, I have also tried it on another wordpress site which has no plug ins and it did not work. The company who provided the code have had success with wordpress sites, however sometimes have come into problems. will there be anything that will be restricting my wordpress from allowing this inline code to work?

Comment: You need to provide specifics about your Wordpress configuration if you want an answer. What steps have you taken to fix this? Did you try to change themes? You also say it doesn't "seem to work". What is it supposed to do and what does it, in fact, do ?

Comment: By copy and pasting the code in http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro you can see what the code does, it creates a live social feed, taken from the script source and places it on the page. However once I feed it through the wordpress html section on the page editor the head section is invisible and the body content which is supposed to display photos only becomes text. since the JS is called from an external link I cant see why its not feeding into the page.

Comment: Isn't that an Angular.js code? If so, you need to implement your entire template using angular.